# How to write a Cout<< Like print function for 16x2 LCD?

Tags: c++, avr, cout, atmel

**Development Environment**

**Controller:** Atmega8
**Language:** C++  (-std=gnu++14  flag added )

**IDE:** atmel studio 7

**Note:** Most of the std:: libraries like ostream ,string ,cout,  are not available with this minimal c++ support.

almost similar functionality has been implemented ,but the function call is different

```
printf1(<object>, ... ); 
 printf1(Lcd4bit2,"Val:",x,'=',5,"+",3.4);
```

I would like to change the code mentioned above ,something like this

`LcdOut<<"Val:"<<m<<'='<<5<<3.4;`,
with minimal and efficient c++ code.

```
class LCD
{
  public:  

  void Write(const char* prnt)  
  {
     //16x2 LCD write code 
  }
};

    void LcdPrint(const char * val,LCD obj)
    {
        obj.Write(val);
    }
    
    void LcdPrint(char val,LCD obj)
    {
        char Str[2];
        sprintf(Str, "%c", val);
        obj.Write(Str);
    }
    
    void LcdPrint(double val,LCD obj)
    {
        char Str[16];
        sprintf(Str, "%f", val);
        obj.Write(Str);
    }
    
    void LcdPrint(int val,LCD obj)
    {
        char Str[16];
        sprintf(Str, "%d", val);
        obj.Write(Str);
    }
    
    template <typename T1,typename T0>
    void printf1(T1 Obj,T0 value) 
    {
        LcdPrint(value,Obj);
    }
    
    template <typename T1,typename T, typename... Ts>
    void printf1(T1 Obj,T value, Ts ... args) 
    {
        LcdPrint(value,Obj);
        printf1(Obj,args...);
    }
    
    int main(void)
    {
        char x ='m';
        Lcd4bit2.SetPos();  // set curser to 0,0 
        printf1(Lcd4bit2,"Val:",x,'=',5,"+",3.4);
    }
```

expected output

[image]

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it? There are some classes that most of us don't know, so please be precise about the problem you are facing.

Comment: @churill
atmega8 has only 8K ROM and 512 byte RAM.
this atmel studio 7 having  very limited set of libraries and most of the std:: library functions are not available. I have seen some ostream like implementations which is not possible with this tiny chip.

Comment: Under those circumstances I'd stick to C. While C++ has value without a Standard Library, it's a <expletive deleted> to code the library from scratch. Behind iostream is a LOT of code. If you're doing this for educational reasons, Awesome. Learning is a great excuse to do stuff you can't afford to do in production.

Comment: @ user4581301
I'm new to c++ , 
yes of course, this is for learning purpose not for production. :)

Comment: @Antonio 
good work , 
how did you set the display position  with cout<<
`Lcd4bit2(4,0)<<"Atmega";
Lcd4bit2(0,1)<<"Val:"<<x<<'='<<5<<'+'<<6.7;`
I did some thing like this  , combining double operator overloading

Comment: @Jestin if you look my implementation of my LCD_HD4480_streambuf, I use a class called `LCD_HD4480_screen`. This class has operation to set de cursor position: `cursor_pos` (and also  cursor_pos_x` and `cursor_pos_y`). I use those functions. But till now I didn't think about it, but maybe you can define an iomanip to select the position of the cursor. Something like: `lcd << cursor_pos(2,4) << "hello"`. If you have never implemented an iomanipulator you can check https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/std/std_iomanip.h

Comment: @Antonio ,
Going through your guthub repo there are enough things to learn for me :)

Comment: I've implemented LCD as a normal ostream. You can check my implementation here:  https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/devices/hwd/dev_HD44780_basic.h. And here https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/devices/hwd/test/HD44780/HD44780/main.cpp you can find an example of how I use it (it works the usual way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want syntactic sugar for some basic output operations you could overload `operator<<` for the required datatypes. You could convert your overloads of `LcdPrint` to something like this:

```
LCD &operator<<(LCD &lcd, double val)
{
    char Str[16];
    sprintf(Str, "%f", val);
    lcd.Write(Str);

    return lcd;
}

LCD &operator<<(LCD &lcd, char val)
{
    char Str[2];
    sprintf(Str, "%c", val);
    lcd.Write(Str);

    return lcd;    
}

// Overload for every required datatype
```

Then you can chain them like this:

```
LCD lcd;
lcd << 0.5 << 'a';
```

Not much different from what you have now, but the syntax looks more C++-ish. I'm also not sure if you need to move the cursor between between these calls, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, This approach is working, I tried something like this. 
I'm not sure my implementation  is correct or not.

`LCD& operator<<(double val)
  {
   char Str[16];
   sprintf(Str, "%f", val);
   Write(Str);
   return *this;
  }`

Comment: position auto increment option is  available with  16x2 LCD chip.
and I think this is the optimal solution for my issue.
Thank you churill for the quick answer.